# Clean/filter HTML inserted to post content by XML RPC

Tags: filters, xml-rpc

An external service that uses XML RPC to publish some posts on my site adds some unwanted CSS styles and HTML to the post content.

I would like to clean it up using a HTML cleaner that I've built based on DOMDocument and DOMXPath.

My only question is how can I access the post_content before it is actually saved to the databse so I can run my cleaner on it? Perhaps there is a filter/action that I can use?

Comment: I'd look into [sanitize_post_field](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L1991). This is a comment, not an answer, because I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

From the [save_post Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post):

> save_post is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by email.

So, if you hook into `save_post` you can run your filter before save:

add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_75871_save_post' );

```
function wpse_75871_save_post( $post_id ) {

    if ( defined( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST' ) && XMLRPC_REQUEST ) {
        // Avoid infinite loops
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_75871_save_post' );

        $post = get_post( $post_id );

        $your_filtered_content = get_your_filtered_content( $post->post_content );

        wp_update_post(
            array(
                'ID' => $post_id, 
                'post_content' => $your_filtered_content 
            )
        );

        add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_75871_save_post' );
    }
}
```

You may need to do some other checking for your specific case. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Is there a way to check if this save_post was triggered by XML-RPC? I would rather use it only for XML-RPC requests, not for all save_post actions, if possible.

Comment: Indeed, it appears a constant XMLRPC_REQUEST is defined - I've updated the code to check against this. I haven't tested, so let me know if that does it!